# extract output from command and pipe it on the command

Tags: linux

So basically I have log files in /var/log/xxx.log. These log files are changed daily so I have to use:
ls -lt /var/log/
in order to figure out the latest logs. I used:

```
ls -lt /var/log/ | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}'
```

to extract the name, however how do I combine it with the directory path without "cd"?
Like:

```
ls -lt /var/log/ | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}' | tail -100 /var/log/[from pipe]
```

Comment: Don't you have journald?

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace `awk '{print $9}' | tail -100 /var/log/[from pipe]` by `tail -100 /var/log/$(awk '{print $9}')`

Answer (score 1):

A better way to find the files inside your directory which have been changed or created less than one day ago is this:

```
find /var/log/ -type f -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1
```

Explanation:

```
-type f     : only look for files
-maxdepth 1 : only look inside this directory
-mtime -1   : only look for the once, being changed at most one day ago
```

Good luck

Comment: Or use [`-daystart`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801095/how-do-i-find-all-the-files-that-were-created-today-in-unix-linux), if you need those files created the current day.